# Appcelerator fires safari when using facebook share

Tags: facebook, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using facebook module's presentShareDialog/authenticate and despite the fact that I have the facebook app installed, safari is launched instead. Any suggestions?

NOTE : I am using SDK 5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for iOS

This is default behaviour. It only opens the Dialog if you're authenticated at Facebook within iOS (Settings > Facebook). NOT the Facebook App!

Comment: Yes this is for iOS. I am properly authenticated at Facebook within iOS but still when using the authenticate or presentShareDialog functions of facebook's module in my Appcelerator app, a safari window opens and I have to enter again username and password.

In the plist tag of tiapp.xml I have the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as described here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Comment: Found this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9. It says using the native app is still possible. Do you happen to know how?
Otherwise I will continue using the Facebook module 4.x for ios.

Comment: @Rubenidis native login is currently an issue, if the fb app is installed on the device fb.authorize() will fail silently. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/pull/46) to get it fixed, should be merged soon enough. Till then I'd stay on 4.x.